# Robot Framework Test - Uploading Picture File To Browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

[Webapp](https://sampleapp.tricentis.com/101/app.php)

Form input tag
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9my9.png)

I am having trouble uploading a picture file unto a form.

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="ideal-file-wrap"><input type="text" class="ideal-file-filename" name="Picture" id="picture"><button type="button" class="ideal-file-upload" tabindex="-1" name="Open" id="open">Open</button></div>
```

Robot Framework File / Keyword:

```
...
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem


*** Keywords ***
Add Profile picture
    
    ${path_to_directory}  Set Variable /Users/miguelbarca/TestAutomation/Vehicle_Insurance_App/Data
    ${file}  Set Variable  malePicture.jpeg
    ${my_locator}  Set Variable  //input[@id='picture']
    

    @{my_file_list}    OperatingSystem.List Files In Directory    ${path_to_directory}

    FOR    ${file}    IN     @{my_file_list}
        ${result}=    Choose File    ${my_locator}    ${path_to_directory}${/}${file}
    END
```

[Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h62nk.png)

The test runs without errors, however the selected jpeg file is not uploaded as expected.

What am I missing?

Documentation:
(https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Choose%20File)

Comment: Draft guess: You need to click on the 'Open' button after `Choose File  ${my_locator} ...` if I get correct UI of your webapp.